# Is there any adb shell command to focus camera?

Tags: adb, camera, focus

I would like to record some movie on my desk but camera doesn't focus so I would like to force my phone to camera focus. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the exact position to touch for focusing the camera, you can use
 `adb shell input tap <x><y>` . This will simulate a touch on the particular `(x,y)` cordinates.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you to download some camera manipulation app like [Vintage Camera by Fine Droid Devs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vintage.camera.free)

though it would have been better if you had mentioned your device.

Answer (score 0):

Before you take a video, focus the camera first.

I had a similar issue with a digital camera (Canon S95). Sometimes, I'd get a blurry video. It turns out that I forgot to focus the camera first, before pressing the record button. The concept would be the same with a phone camera.